# TensorFlow or Theano: how do they know the loss function derivative based on the neural network graph?

Tags: neural-network, theano, tensorflow

In TensorFlow or Theano, you only tell the library how your neural network is, and how feed-forward should operate.

For instance, in TensorFlow, you would write:

```
with graph.as_default():
    _X = tf.constant(X)
    _y = tf.constant(y)

    hidden = 20
    w0 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([X.shape[1], hidden]))
    b0 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden]))

    h = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(_X, w0) + b0)

    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden, 1]))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1]))

    yp = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h, w1) + b1)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(0.5*tf.square(yp - _y))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
```

I am using L2-norm loss function, C=0.5*sum((y-yp)^2), and in the backpropagation step presumably the derivative will have to be computed, dC=sum(y-yp). See [(30) in this book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html).

My question is: how can TensorFlow (or Theano) know the analytical derivative for backpropagation? Or do they do an approximation? Or somehow do not use the derivative?

I have done the [deep learning udacity course](https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning--ud730) on TensorFlow, but I am still at odds at how to make sense on how these libraries work.

Comment: Here is a related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210561/how-do-backpropagation-works-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The differentiation happens in the final line:

```
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
```

When you execute the `minimize()` method, TensorFlow identifies the set of variables on which `loss` depends, and computes gradients for each of these. The differentiation is implemented in [`ops/gradients.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py), and it uses ["reverse accumulation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Reverse_accumulation). Essentially it searches backwards from the `loss` tensor to the variables, applying the chain rule at each operator in the dataflow graph. TensorFlow includes "gradient functions" for most (differentiable) operators, and you can see an example of how these are implemented in [`ops/math_grad.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py). A gradient function can use the original op (including its inputs, outputs, and attributes) and the gradients computed for each of its outputs to produce gradients for each of its inputs.

Page 7 of [Ilya Sutskever's PhD thesis](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~ilya/pubs/ilya_sutskever_phd_thesis.pdf) has a nice explanation of how this process works in general.

Comment: I wonder if the derivative can be calculated automatically whether I define my loss function via python or via tf operation?

Comment: It knows all the individual derivatives (in case of existence) of the tf operations, not of the python operations.

Comment: So the loss function must be a loss function provided by the TensorFlow library? Because TensorFlow already stores the expression of the loss function's first-order derivative? Does PyTorch work similarly? I noticed in the example of reverse accumulation within the Wikipedia link, the first derivative of `sin()` is already known to be `cos()`.