# How do backpropagation works in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow it seems that the entire backpropagation algorithm is performed by a single running of an optimizer on a certain cost function, which is the output of some MLP or a CNN.

I do not fully understand how tensorflow knows from the cost that it is indeed an output of a certain NN? A cost function can be defined for any model. How should I "tell" it that a certain cost function derives from a NN?

Comment: You should read about how DL libraries work and specifically graph computation. tldr: the cost function is a node on a graph and the edges (weights) are coming from the network's last layer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Question

How should I "tell" tf that a certain cost function derives from a NN?

## (short) Answer

This is done by simply configuring your optimizer to minimize (or maximize) a tensor.  For example, if I have a loss function like so

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( y0 - y_out ) )
```

where y0 is the **ground truth** (or desired output) and y_out is the calculated output, then I could minimize the loss by defining my training function like so

```
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)
```

This tells Tensorflow that when **train** is calculated, it is to apply gradient descent on loss to minimize it, and loss is calculated using y0 and y_out, and so gradient descent will also affect those (if they are trainable variables), and so on.

The variable **y0**, **y_out**, **loss**, and **train** are not standard python variables but instead descriptions of a computation graph.  Tensorflow uses information about that computation graph to unroll it while applying gradient descent.

Specifically how it does that is beyond the scope of this answer.  [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257746/how-does-tensorflow-tf-train-optimizer-compute-gradients) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) are two good starting points for more information about more specifics.

## Code Example

Let's walk through a code example.  First the code.

```
### imports
import tensorflow as tf

### constant data
x  = [[0.,0.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.]]
y_ = [[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.]]

### induction
# 1x2 input -> 2x3 hidden sigmoid -> 3x1 sigmoid output

# Layer 0 = the x2 inputs
x0 = tf.constant( x  , dtype=tf.float32 )
y0 = tf.constant( y_ , dtype=tf.float32 )

# Layer 1 = the 2x3 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [2,3] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [3]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
h1 = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x0,m1 ) + b1 )

# Layer 2 = the 3x1 sigmoid output
m2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [3,1] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [1]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
y_out = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( h1,m2 ) + b2 )


### loss
# loss : sum of the squares of y0 - y_out
loss = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( y0 - y_out ) )

# training step : gradient decent (1.0) to minimize loss
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)


### training
# run 500 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
  for step in range(500) :
    sess.run(train)

  results = sess.run([m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss])
  labels  = "m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss".split(",")
  for label,result in zip(*(labels,results)) :
    print ""
    print label
    print result

print ""
```

Let's go through it, but in reverse order starting with

```
sess.run(train)
```

This tells tensorflow to look up the graph node defined by **train** and calculate it.  **Train** is defined as

```
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)
```

To calculate this tensorflow must compute the *automatic differentiation* for **loss**, which means walking the graph.  **loss** is defined as

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( y0 - y_out ) )
```

Which is really tensorflow applying *automatic differentiation* to unroll first **tf.reduce_sum**, then **tf.square**, then **y0 - y_out**, which leads to then having to walk the graph for both y0 and y_out.

```
y0 = tf.constant( y_ , dtype=tf.float32 )
```

**y0** is a constant and will not be updated.

```
y_out = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( h1,m2 ) + b2 )
```

**y_out** will be processed similar to loss, first **tf.sigmoid** will be processed, etc...

All in all, each operation ( such as tf.sigmoid, tf.square ) not only defines the forward operation ( apply sigmoid or square ) but also information necessary for *automatic differentiation*.  This is different than standard python math such as

```
x = 7 + 9
```

The above equation encodes nothing except how to update x, where as

```
z = y0 - y_out
```

encodes the graph of subtracting y_out from y0 and stores both the forward operation and enough to do *automatic differentiation* in **z**

Comment: This was very helpfull ! Thanks a lot. I couldn't find this kind of information in other websites. They just demonstarte codes with instructions without explaining what is going on behind it. Can you recommend me on website with more deeper explanations on TF? A place which also explains the rationality behind this unique progaraming paradigm.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  There isn't anything that I read.  How I got a better understanding is that I made a small study course for myself then did it.  Here is the link : https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow and I actually did what I wrote in the README.  It took about an hour a day for several weeks to get up to *Level 4 - Solo* on all the challenges without cheating.  Once I hit *Level 4 - Solo*, Tensorflow felt very natural even though I only worked through small examples.

Answer (score 2):

The [backpropagation](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Evincentp/ift3395/lectures/backprop_old.pdf) was created by Rumelhart and Hinton et al and published [on Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/323533a0) in 1986.

As stated in section [6.5: Back-Propagation and Other DiﬀerentiationAlgorithms](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html#page=200)  of the [deeplearning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) there are two types of approaches for back-propagation gradients through computational graphs: symbol-to-number differentiation and symbol to symbol derivatives. The more relevant one to Tensorflow as stated in this paper: [A Tour of TensorFlow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01178) is the later which can be illustrated using this diagram:

[image]

Source: Section II Part D of [A Tour of TensorFlow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01178)

In left side of the the Fig. 7 above, w represents the weights(or Variables) in Tensorflow and x and y are two intermediary operations(or nodes, w, x, y and z are all operations) to get the scalar loss z.

Tensorflow will add a node to each node(if we print the names of variables in a certain checkpoint we can see some additional variables for such nodes and they will be eliminated if we freeze the model to a protocol buffer file for deployment) in the graph for the gradient which can be seen in diagram (b) on the right side: dz/dy, dy/dx, dx/dw.

During the traversal of the back propagation at each node we multiply its gradient with that of the previous one and finally to get a symbolic handle to the overall target derivative dz/dw = dz/dy * dy/dx * dx/dw, which applies exactly the chain rule. Once the gradient is worked out w can update itself with a learning rate.

For more detailed information please read this paper: [TensorFlow:
Large-Scale Machine Learning on Heterogeneous Distributed Systems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04467.pdf)